# Position image background-position programmatically when zoom is 125% in Chrome shaking issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

***Scenario:*** I'm doing a small fun web app, which achieves the effect as if user digged a hole in a black-overlay image and could see part of the original image through the hole.
The implementation is just position the background image programmatically based on the hole's position on the black-overlay image. With this implementation, it feels like user is looking at part of the original image through the hole.

***Problem:***
On chrome with zoom level at 125%, when I move the hole around, I can obviously feel the background image shakes and the shaking range is about 1px.
The implementation works perfectly in Edge, Firefox at any zoom level. On chrome with 100% zoom, I cannot feel the jitter as well.

***Tried:*** I felt like it might be a chrome subpixel rending issue but after I Math.floor/Math.ceil the Left and Top values, it can still reproduce.
Could anyone shed some light on what's the issue is and how to get around it?

The following jsfiddle can help reproduce the issue if you open it with Chrome and adjust browser zoom level to 125%. https://jsfiddle.net/cxpjckpe/

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;

  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    var newTop = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2;
    var newLeft = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1;
    elmnt.style.top = newTop + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = newLeft + "px";

    elmnt.style["background-image"] = 'url("https://www.ci.lubbock.tx.us/images/parks-rec-images/stumpy-hamilton-park.jpg?sfvrsn=950e9723_2")';
    elmnt.style["background-repeat"] = "no-repeat";
    elmnt.style["background-position"] = "-" + newLeft + "px " + "-" + newTop + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 480px; background-image: url('https://www.ci.lubbock.tx.us/images/parks-rec-images/stumpy-hamilton-park.jpg?sfvrsn=950e9723_2');">
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"></div>
  <div id="mydiv" style="border: 2px solid white; width: 100px; height: 100px;">

  </div>
</div>
```